# Relying on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been tasked with creating an extremely heavy JavaScript site that of course must be backwards compatible as well as work on pad devices, dynamically resize, etc...

Does anyone have advice on how to help with the reliability of the code?  Currently, a lot happens when the DOM is ready.  E.g. graphics are scaled, click events are defined, etc...

However, if a file is slow or the user stops the load, the DOM ready doesn't always execute causing the images to not resize properly or some other Javascript function to execute.

Most times everything works flawlessly, but there are those odd times with network connectivity that cause a few "random" issues.

Would love to hear some thoughts on improving the reliability.

Comment: Why do you resize images on the client side using JavaScript? Wouldn't it be more suitable to your needs to use CSS media query and custom style sheets with pre scaled graphics? Use scripts to load your resources.

Comment: @Mithrandir - what happens if I rotate my smartphone, if the graphics adjusts that is great, your way they need to be downloaded all over, which can be slow.  Not certain if that is the rationale, but it makes sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Load all your content via JavaScript.**

This way you can make sure all of the libraries needed are loaded before the application is displayed.  You can also use a nice loading screen if it isn't a quick download, and can possibly detect loading issues.  Of course, this is only for web applications that absolutely must use JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting idea.  I could see this being useful to download lots of images using multiple CDN sub domains to get around the browsers async issues with content from the same domain.

Comment: Lazy loading - loading the page in "chunks" might be good idea indeed.

Answer (score 1):

To help limit the possibility that someone will stop the load, you may want to start with profiling your page, including the javascript, and see where things are slow.

If some images are slow, have them load after the page is done, with some information to let the user know that images will be coming.

Then you can prioritize what is done, for example.

But, until you get some performance numbers anything you do is guessing, and that is risky, IMO.